# Virtualization software for windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtualization

I've been using Shadow User and Deep freeze for windows xp. But I don't think its compatible with windows 7. Do you know of any application that can achieve the same thing?
Please don't tell me to use Returnil virtual system because I've had a really bad experience with it when I'm using xp. The system just restarted over and over. And I have just reformatted by that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of [**Deep Freeze, 6.62,**](http://www.faronics.com/standard/deep-freeze/) is fully compatible with Windows 7.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I dont think these are virtualisation software, but anyhow MS do one called Steady State, it says on the website that it supports XP and Vista, it doesnt say anything about 7 but it may well work. Unfortunatly I dont have a 7 PC to use it on so have never tried it.

Here is a link to steady state product page

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/sharedaccess/default.mspx

and one for the download page

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=D077A52D-93E9-4B02-BD95-9D770CCDB431&displaylang=en

Comment: I've also tried this in xp before and I'm not satisfied by the way it performs. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

http://www.virtualbox.org/ - it's free to some extent.

I use it every day, it is very good. I have previously use Hyper-V, and this is VBox is OK in comparison.

Comment: He is not after virtual machines

Comment: Sorry, it thought that by "Virtualization software for windows 7" he meant VMs.